# How to make substring() read a string until a certain character?

Tags: java, string, substring

I want to create a substring say:

```
String s1 = "derp123";

s2 = s1.substring(0, *index where there's a number*);
```

Is there any way I can achieve this other than by using the replaceAll method?

I don't want to replace all the numbers in the String, I want to stop reading the string once the method detects a number `0-9`.

Comment: That sounds like you need a basic regex.

Comment: `s1.replaceAll("\\d.*", "")` probably does the trick...

Comment: Note that replaceAll doesn't modify your existing string; it makes a new string.

Comment: `for(int i...) if s1.charAt(i) is '0'-'9' return s1.substring(0,i)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want.

```
String s1 = "derp123";
String patternStr = "[0-9]";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(patternStr).matcher(s1);
if (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(s1.substring(0, matcher.start()));
}
```

And this will give you the string part without numbers

Comment: Note that this will skip the print statement if string does not contain any digits, where OP might want entire string printed.

Comment: Yes. But his main issue is to remove any numbers if a string contains them. He can work out the rest with an else condition.

Answer (score 2):

For this, regular expression is your friend.

I'll just show you the code for your example, but you should learn more about the power (and limitations) of regular expressions. See javadoc of [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

```
String s1 = "derp123";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^\\D*").matcher(s1);
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group()); // prints: derp
```

Note that the [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method shown in comments is also using a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Since OP said that he did not want to use `replace` and therefore regex this is my suggestion. Note, the REGEX version already given is much more elegant in my opinion I'm only providing this to show that are others ways to do so.

```
String s1 = "blahblah1234";
String s2 = s1.substring(0, firstNumberPos(s1));
System.out.println(s2);
```

And the `firstNumberPos` definition

```
public static int firstNumberPos(String str){
    for ( int i=0; i<str.length(); i++ ){
        if ( str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9'){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return str.length();
}
```

Note that I didn't care about the null points, you still have to check it.

Comment: dude.... these chars (0-9) have consecutive values. just check `>='0'` and `<='9'` is enough.